# Download file without prompting save or open with php

Tags: javascript, php, browser

I search lot about this, but did not get any solution.
I want to download files without prompting suggestion dialog box, because there are bunch of files say 200.

> [PHP automatically downloads file without prompting to save or open file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23447518/php-automatically-downloads-file-without-prompting-to-save-or-open-file)

With the reference of above, I came to know this is browser related issue but is there any way we can force browser to download file using php or javascript.

I am getting below popup which should be skipped.

[image]

Any suggestion would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I can't say 100% but on the surface this seems like if possible, it'd be a huge security problem

Comment: Why do you not use a lib to compress the files and have them download the compressed folder?

Comment: @ponury-kostek I know its duplicate and I mentioned in my question also, but it does not have an answer which I am looking for.

Comment: Yeah, 'cause the answer you *want* doesn't exist.

Comment: @deceze okay, but is there any way where I can give download path on user system where all the files gets downloaded. As in chrome it gets downloaded directly as it does not prompt any popup to save or open.

Comment: That would be a huge security concern! Further, you don't typically have any idea about what folders do or don't exist on your visitor's machine, neither would it be any of your business.

Comment: Okay. Thank you for your time.